# Print to PDF en PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Existe alguna manera de simular este comportamiento de los navegadores? Cuando abrimos un pdf en un navegador, y le damos en imprimir, **siempre sale la opcion de Guardar como Pdf (o Print to PDF en ingles)**. Quisiera saber si esto **se puede trasladar a PHP de alguna manera**, con alguna libreria. Me encuentro realizando un programa que combina diferentes pdfs en uno solo, pero este programa me da error con pdfs que tienen encriptacion, a pesar de que tengan una clave en blanco en su encriptacion, por lo cual estos pdfs se logran visualizar desde navegador, pero no se dejan procesar con PHP. **Este problema se arregla si yo le doy en guardar como pdf**, puesto que se pierde la encriptacion y el navegador genera un formato nuevo de pdf. Existe alguna manera de simular este comportamiento?

Comment: entiendo tu problema, pero se me hace un poco complicado de reproducir, así que tal vez recibas poca ayuda de la comunidad